# how can I show users who has only one session opened?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

How do i find users who has only one session opened? I know I can find who has multiple session opened using:

```
who | cut -d " " -f 1 | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-u` switch to only output the unique values.

```
who | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq -u
```

You need to sort the usernames, though, as `uniq` expects the input to be sorted. That's true for the `-d` solution, too, unless your version of `who` already groups the lines by user (and the one I have accessible (GNU 8.28) doesn't).

Comment: in this way, aren't users who have multiple sessions opened will be shown as well?

Comment: Wait, maybe you need to sort the list first, let me test...

Comment: @Aaron: Fixed, it should work now.

Comment: it works. Thank you!